# Summing a range of cells and perform a countif on that range in one formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge data dump that has lots of duplicates. Lets say that its a list of customer IDs. I have a `=IF(COUNTIF($@$#:@#,@#)>1,0,1)` to only count the new customer ID if its not duplicated above.

Lets say I didn't want to have one column for the 1s and 0s for customer IDs but instead wanted one formula that would sum all distinct IDs or in other words sum all the 1s in the above formula. Is this possible in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula counts the number of unique values in a range if IDs contains only numbers:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($@$#:@#,$@$#:@#)>0,1))
```

or use this one if you want to count the number of unique text or a mix between numbers and text:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH($@$#:@#,$@$#:@#,0),MATCH($@$#:@#,$@$#:@#,0))>0,1))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I haven't used the frequency formula before and am having trouble applying it to my situation. Should the data_array and the bins_array be the same range? For some reason the value is returning 0

Comment: Nevermind, the match function works since the customer ID field has text. Thanks!